# How do I not extract text from a cropped out part of A PDF Page in Python3 with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a pdf where I need to both split the page in half and extract text from each half of the page. Using python3 and the PyPDF2 library, it was pretty easy to crop the pages in half; however, when trying to extract the text from the cropped pages, it's still loading text in the half of the page that was cropped out. This is currently my implementation for cropping the pages:

```
inputFile = open(PDF_NAME, "rb")
input1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(inputFile)
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
numPages = input1.getNumPages()
for i in range(numPages):
    page = input1.getPage(i)
    page.cropBox.lowerRight = (page.cropBox.lowerRight[0]/2, 0)
    output.addPage(page)
out_f = open("output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(out_f)
out_f.close()
```

Which is pretty straightforward. This is my implementation for loading the texts from the pages of the output file:

```
f = open(PDF_NAME, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
pageTexts = []
for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    pageText = pageObj.extractText()
    pageTexts.append(pageText)
f.close()
```

Which are still picking up the text from the cropped-out part of the pages (I guess they're just hidden rather than actually deleted).
Is there any way to properly delete a part of the pdf page rather than just cropping it?

Comment: This is possible, but currently not easy with PyPDF2. https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/pull/1252 would make it easier, but it might take 2 weeks until it gets merged

Comment: Also https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/discussions/1181#discussioncomment-3413144